# Computational check whether $G\cong \tilde G$

Tags: group-theory, computational-mathematics

Unless I was mistaken somewhere in the proof, the following claim should hold:

**Claim**. Let $G, \tilde G$ be groups. Then, $G\cong\tilde G$ if and only if there are a set $S$ and two bijections, $f\colon S\to G$ and $\tilde f\colon S\to \tilde G$, such that:

$$\tilde f^{-1}(\tilde f(s)\tilde f(t))=f^{-1}(f(s)f(t)), \space\space\forall s,t \in S\tag 1$$

(Operation symbol is omitted in both groups.) As a first test of $(1)$, I'd like to show by brute force that, if $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$, $\tilde G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then:

$$\forall \alpha,\beta =1,\dots,24, \exists i,j \in S \mid f_\alpha^{-1}(f_\alpha(i)+f_\alpha(j)) \ne \tilde f_\beta^{-1}(\tilde f_\beta(i)+\tilde f_\beta(j)) \tag 2$$

where $\{f_\alpha, \alpha=1,\dots,24\}=\operatorname{Sym}(S,G)$ and $\{\tilde f_\alpha, \alpha=1,\dots,24\}=\operatorname{Sym}(S,\tilde G)$, $\operatorname{Sym}(X,Y)$ being the set of bijections from $X$ to $Y$.

> Is there any available fast resource to computationally check $(2)$?

Comment: To divide your work by $24$, note that it is enough to check $(2)$ for one $\alpha$.

Comment: You don't need that auxiliary S, just give a bijection between the underlying sets of the groups.

Comment: Not really, but your $(1)$ can be "improved" by saying that you can allow yourself to fix just one $f$, and make only $f'$ vary. This should be more or less clear if you think about the fact that you can directly work with bijections $G\to \tilde{G}$.

Comment: What does Sym$(S,G)$ mean?

Comment: @AHusain I don't think that the linked question really answers this question.  The only answer there is a link to a blog post, without any further detail.   I think that this question is also posed in a manner that is much more in line with MSE standards, hence I think that the best option might be to consider closing and/or deleting the older question, and providing a quality answer to this question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I suppose so. Reopen voted.